# SQL help Calculating Employee Overtime hours with 2 jobs in the same company

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database, mariadb

I'm trying to calculate regular an overtime hours for an employee that works 2 jobs at the same company. The reason it needs to be done this way, is the hours get billed to separate departments. Overtime begins after the employee works 40 total hours, and anything beyond is considered Overtime for the respective job. I basically need (4) different numbers out of the sql statement. I need:

```
Job 1 Regular hours
Job 1 Overtime hours
Job 2 Regular hours
Job 2 Overtime hours
```

My current sql query to achieve the table below is:

```
SELECT clockPunch.punchinTime, clockPunch.punchoutTime, clockPunch.job, ROUND(CEIL((TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(clockPunch.punchoutTime, clockPunch.punchinTime))/3600.0)*10)/10, 2) AS timedifference FROM clockPunch WHERE clockPunch.employee_id=1 order by punchinTime DESC
```

My current table looks like below:

```
employee    punchinTime           punchoutTime             job     timedifference
1           2023-06-22 08:00:00   2023-06-22 17:00:00      1       9.00
1           2023-06-23 09:00:00   2023-06-23 17:30:00      1       8.50
1           2023-06-24 11:00:00   2023-06-24 20:00:00      2       9.00
1           2023-06-25 09:00:00   2023-06-25 17:00:00      1       8.00
1           2023-06-26 13:00:00   2023-06-26 23:00:00      2       10.00
1           2023-06-27 14:30:00   2023-06-28 01:00:00      2       10.50
1           2023-06-28 14:00:00   2023-06-28 19:00:00      2       5.00
1           2023-06-29 09:00:00   2023-06-29 17:00:00      1       8.00
```

For the above data, I am trying to write a new query, but am unsure how to. I want the new query to show the following result:

```
Job 1 Regular hours: 25.50
Job 1 Overtime hours: 8.00
Job 2 Regular hours: 14.50
Job 2 Overtime hours: 20.00
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to achieve this through an sql query?

Comment: If I'd ask you if you could add four queries for those four result lines, would you be able to [edit] them into your question?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking

Comment: for the four data-points you are looking for, share the four SQL queries that get them. are you able to? if so, [edit] your question and show those four queries. If not, [edit] and explain why not.

Comment: I was not able to successfully generate those queries, That is what I need help writing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `SUM()` as a window function to get the cumulative total hours:

```sql
SELECT
    punchinTime, punchoutTime, job,
    ROUND(CEIL((TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(punchoutTime, punchinTime))/3600.0)*10)/10, 2) AS timedifference,
    SUM(ROUND(CEIL((TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(punchoutTime, punchinTime))/3600.0)*10)/10, 2)) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id ORDER BY punchinTime ASC) AS cumulative_hours
FROM clockPunch
WHERE employee_id = 1
ORDER BY punchinTime ASC;
```

Which will output:

| punchinTime | punchoutTime | job | timedifference | cumulative_hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-22 08:00:00 | 2023-06-22 17:00:00 | 1 | 9.00 | 9.00 |
| 2023-06-23 09:00:00 | 2023-06-23 17:30:00 | 1 | 8.50 | 17.50 |
| 2023-06-24 11:00:00 | 2023-06-24 20:00:00 | 2 | 9.00 | 26.50 |
| 2023-06-25 09:00:00 | 2023-06-25 17:00:00 | 1 | 8.00 | 34.50 |
| 2023-06-26 13:00:00 | 2023-06-26 23:00:00 | 2 | 10.00 | 44.50 |
| 2023-06-27 14:30:00 | 2023-06-28 01:00:00 | 2 | 10.50 | 55.00 |
| 2023-06-28 14:00:00 | 2023-06-28 19:00:00 | 2 | 5.00 | 60.00 |
| 2023-06-29 09:00:00 | 2023-06-29 17:00:00 | 1 | 8.00 | 68.00 |

Now we can use the above query as a derived table and figure out which hours are regular and which are overtime:

```sql
SELECT *,
    CASE
        WHEN cumulative_hours <= 40 THEN timedifference
        WHEN cumulative_hours - timedifference <= 40 THEN 40 - (cumulative_hours - timedifference)
    END AS regular_hours,
    CASE
        WHEN cumulative_hours - timedifference >= 40 THEN timedifference
        WHEN cumulative_hours > 40 THEN cumulative_hours - 40
    END AS overtime_hours
FROM (
    SELECT
        punchinTime, punchoutTime, job,
        ROUND(CEIL((TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(punchoutTime, punchinTime))/3600.0)*10)/10, 2) AS timedifference,
        SUM(ROUND(CEIL((TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(punchoutTime, punchinTime))/3600.0)*10)/10, 2)) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id ORDER BY punchinTime ASC) AS cumulative_hours
    FROM clockPunch
    WHERE employee_id = 1
    ORDER BY punchinTime ASC
) t1;
```

Which give us:

| punchinTime | punchoutTime | job | timedifference | cumulative_hours | regular_hours | overtime_hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-22 08:00:00 | 2023-06-22 17:00:00 | 1 | 9.00 | 9.00 | 9.00 |  |
| 2023-06-23 09:00:00 | 2023-06-23 17:30:00 | 1 | 8.50 | 17.50 | 8.50 |  |
| 2023-06-24 11:00:00 | 2023-06-24 20:00:00 | 2 | 9.00 | 26.50 | 9.00 |  |
| 2023-06-25 09:00:00 | 2023-06-25 17:00:00 | 1 | 8.00 | 34.50 | 8.00 |  |
| 2023-06-26 13:00:00 | 2023-06-26 23:00:00 | 2 | 10.00 | 44.50 | 5.50 | 4.50 |
| 2023-06-27 14:30:00 | 2023-06-28 01:00:00 | 2 | 10.50 | 55.00 |  | 10.50 |
| 2023-06-28 14:00:00 | 2023-06-28 19:00:00 | 2 | 5.00 | 60.00 |  | 5.00 |
| 2023-06-29 09:00:00 | 2023-06-29 17:00:00 | 1 | 8.00 | 68.00 |  | 8.00 |

And then to pull it all together we can group by `job`:

```sql
SELECT job,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN cumulative_hours <= 40 THEN timedifference
            WHEN cumulative_hours - timedifference <= 40 THEN 40 - (cumulative_hours - timedifference)
        END
    ) AS regular_hours,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN cumulative_hours - timedifference >= 40 THEN timedifference
            WHEN cumulative_hours > 40 THEN cumulative_hours - 40
        END
    ) AS overtime_hours
FROM (
    SELECT
        punchinTime, punchoutTime, job,
        ROUND(CEIL((TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(punchoutTime, punchinTime))/3600.0)*10)/10, 2) AS timedifference,
        SUM(ROUND(CEIL((TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(punchoutTime, punchinTime))/3600.0)*10)/10, 2)) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id ORDER BY punchinTime ASC) AS cumulative_hours
    FROM clockPunch
    WHERE employee_id=1
    ORDER BY punchinTime ASC
) t1
GROUP BY job;
```

Et voilà:

| job | regular_hours | overtime_hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25.50 | 8.00 |
| 2 | 14.50 | 20.00 |

Your demo data is Thursday to Thursday inclusive so I have not added the partitioning or grouping by week, but hopefully this enough to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to write out a complete query to do everything you need, but this will calculate how many total hours the employee has worked after the current punch out:

```
  SELECT employee, 
         punchinTime, 
         punchoutTime,
         job, 
         timedifference,
         @timevar := @timevar + timedifference AS timetodate
  FROM clockPunch
  CROSS JOIN (select @timevar := 0.0) timevar
  ORDER BY punchinTime;
```

After this, you can calculate how much time from the current punch is overtime by subtracting 40 from the total. Whichever value is smaller, the remainder of the total or the value in timedifference, is the overtime from that punchin.

Then it is a matter of using some aggregate functions to sum up your overtime and regular hours by job.

NOTE: This does not take into consideration the fact that there are times from multiple weeks in the provided data. The `WEEKOFYEAR()` function will help in grouping each weeks worth of data together.